# OXID - Custom controller not working through address bar

Tags: oxid

I have created a custom module in oxidshop and added a controller through metadata.php

```
'files' => array(
        'mycustom' => 'application/controllers/MycustomController.php'
    ),
```

The code for MycustomController is same as the BasketController.php. I have been using it for testing. However, the request http://shopurl/index.php?cl=mycustom redirects to homepage. Any idea?

Comment: first, you need to check log/exception_log.txt for the exact reason, why you were redirected to start page

Comment: I am getting `OXID Logger.ERROR: EXCEPTION_SYSTEMCOMPONENT_CLASSNOTFOUND` error. Btw I am running this installation on Windows 10 laptop.